# Python Socket Setup

Tags: python

I'm trying to setup a basic socket program using TCP connections in Python, such as creating a socket, binding it to a specific address and port, as well as sending and receiving a HTTP packet.

I'm having trouble receiving the request message from the client.

I'm using the following:

message = serverSocket.receive

But when I go to the socket, port and file that's in my server directory through my browser I get the following error from IDLE:

AttributeError: 'socket' object has no attribute 'receive'

Is this the wrong approach to receive a request message from a client?

Comment: Without seeing your entire program we can't be much help at all, but ... the tiny fragment you did show is so utterly different from the actual way this would be done in Python that I have to wonder whether you are reading a tutorial for the wrong programming language.  Could you please tell us where you heard that `serverSocket.receive` was the thing to do?

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

In order to receive data from a client/server via TCP in python using sockets:

`someData = sock.recv(1024)`

Answer (score 0):

That is because no method is defined in the socket class for `receive` as your error states. You should use:

```
socket.recv(bufsize)
```